# How to render Image from file using the Qt OpenGL API

Tags: image, qt, opengl

I'm trying to render an image from a *.png file on to screen using the Qt OpenGL API. My implement method creates the OpenGLWindow class, which is subclass of QOpenGLWindow and QOpenGLFunctions, then overrides 2 methods: initializeGL() and paintGL().

I have code, as below:

```
class OpenGLWindow : public QOpenGLWindow, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OpenGLWindow();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
    : QOpenGLWindow(QOpenGLWindow::NoPartialUpdate)
{
}

void OpenGLWindow::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
}

void OpenGLWindow::paintGL()
{
    // Clear buffer with blue color
    glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Load image from file
    QImage image;
    if(!image.load(":/side1.png"))
    {
        qDebug() << "load image fail";
        return;
    }    

    // Draw Texture
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable texturing
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID); // Obtain an id for the texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); // Set as the current texture
    QImage tex = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(image);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex.width(), tex.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.bits());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

The result is the window only displays a blue screen, with an error that the image could not be displayed. I saw that the image was loaded successfully to QImage. Have I don't something wrong or am I missing something or not? Can somebody help me?

Result screen:

[image]

Comment: First of all you are loading the image every time that the scene is rendered, you should move the loading and the texture creation in the initialize phase. Than there's no rendering code, you aren't drawing anything

Comment: Fabio, Thanks you for your comment ! I agree that should move the loading and the texture creation in the initialize phase, i will do it but can you explain more detail about rendering code ? I have not yet find it.

Comment: To render your texture you can (e.g.) draw a texturized rectangle. [Here](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html) a simple example using `glBegin()` / `glEnd()` and [here](https://open.gl/textures) an example using vertex array

Comment: Thanks Fabio ! I resolved it by vertex array.